# Proving $|(x-x_0)(x-x_1)|\leq \frac {1}{4}(x_1-x_0)^2$

Tags: inequality

I need to prove that 
$$
|(x-x_0)(x-x_1)|\leq \frac {1}{4}(x_1-x_0)^2
$$
for all $x\in < x_0 ; x_1 >$

The only thing I have notived it that the expression with absoltue value is always non-positive, so the inequality is equvalent to 
$$
-(x-x_0)(x-x_1)\leq \frac {1}{4}(x_1-x_0)^2
$$
but I'm stuck here

Comment: Use MG- AM inequality

Comment: @dmtri so I have achieved form $4x(x_1-x+x_0)\leq (x_0+x_1)^2$ and that I can prove using $4xy\leq (x+y)^2$? Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note

$$0\le (x-\frac{x_0+x_1}2)^2$$

and $$( \frac{x_1-x_0}2)^2 - (x-\frac{x_1+x_0}2)^2 \le 
( \frac{x_1-x_0}2)^2  $$

Thus,

$$(x_1-x)(x-x_0) \le \frac14( x_1-x_0)^2  $$

Comment: could you also help me with question, that is generalisation of this problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3640493/proving-fracb-ab-x-cdot-fracb-ak1k1-geq-fracb-akk1

Comment: @MartinYakuza - will take a look

Answer (score 2):

For $ x \in (x_0, x_1)$, you have $(x-x_0) + (x_1-x) = x_1-x_0$.

Then prove (it's not difficult) that the product of two numbers whose sum is constant is maximum when those two numbers are equal.

Apply that to your case, $\left\vert(x-x_0)(x-x_1) \right\vert$ is maximum when $x-x_0 = x_1-x = \frac{x_1-x_0}{2}$ and therefore the maximum is indeed equal to $\frac{(x_1-x_0)^2}{4}$.

Comment: proving that fact you mentioned is that when we have sum of two numbers equal s, then product is x(s-x) so we have roots in 0 and s, so the max value is halfway between them so it's in s/2, right?

Comment: Yes. You can also make a proof by taking the derivative of $g(x)=x(s-x)$.

Comment: Yes, but I don't really see the point of derivating parabola to find it's maximum

Comment: $g(x)=(x-x_0)(x-x_1) $ is the equation of a parabola!

Comment: I imagine that you know that to find the extrema of a function, its derivative is important?!?

Comment: Yeah, but it's a well know fact, that the extrema of parabola is in it's vertex