# Proving $\frac{b-a}{b-x}\cdot (\frac{b-a}{k+1})^{k+1}\geq (\frac{b-a}{k})^{k+1}$

Tags: inequality, induction, products

Prove that:
$$
|\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)|\leq\frac{n!}{4}(\frac{b-a}{n})^{n+1}
$$
where $x_i=a+i\frac{b-a}{n}$ for $i=0,...,n$ and $x\in [a;b]$

I have tried to do induction: I proved it for $n=1$ and now I need to do prove the second step of induction - proof for $n=k+1$

I found out that $x_{k+1}=b$, and I divided both sided of inequality by $|x-x_{k+1}|=b-x$ (in case $x=x_{k+1}$, the proof is  trivial)

and now I basically just need to prove, that:
$$
\frac{b-a}{b-x}\cdot (\frac{b-a}{k+1})^{k+1}\geq (\frac{b-a}{k})^{k+1}
$$
any tips on how to do it?

Comment: Can you be more precise. I.e. do you mean that the inequality $\frac{b-a}{b-x}\cdot (\frac{b-a}{k+1})^{k+1}\geq (\frac{b-a}{k})^{k+1}$ is valid for any $x \in (a,b)$ and $k \in \mathbb N$? If this is what you mean, then this is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  conjecture is not true:

We can simplify it to

$$\frac{b-a}{b-x} \ge \left( \frac{k+1}{k}\right)^{k+1}$$

If $k=1$, then the RHS is $4$.

Now pick $b=1, a=0$, and $x=\frac12$, we have LHS$=2$ which is a contradiction. In fact, we can choose $x$ such that the LHS gets arbitrarily close to $1$.

Your original question has been answerd [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906714/maximum-of-error-in-equidistant-interpolation).